# Charts.js not using the right colors

Tags: javascript, chart.js

js for plot charts in my application, but it's not using the right colors, I am pasting a jsfiddle here for see if someone can see something wrong, (my problem is two section with the same color, even when I specify it different, and when I hover the section "two" the three also highlight)

```js
var c = document.getElementById('mcanvas');
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var data = [
{"value":1,"label":"One","color":"#6e2a89","highlight":"#f00"},{"value":1,"label":"Two","color":"#b26b65","highlight":"#f00"},{"value":3,"label":"Three","color":"#f42be","highlight":"#f00"},{"value":1,"label":"Four","color":"#57b893","highlight":"#f00"},{"value":7,"label":"Five","color":"#4b8752","highlight":"#f00"},{"value":0,"label":"Six","color":"#ff7e9","highlight":"#f00"}];
var ch = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data, {});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="mcanvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your color for three is 5 digits. Not sure exactly why this is causing this behavior. But fixing that will solve your problem.

Comment: Yes yes thanks you are right, the things is I am generating random colors and when the color is one digit I need to fill zeros, thank you!